# How to handle Strict Transport Security (HSTS) using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, hsts

I'm trying to record traffic off a website which uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS). As a result it is not possible to add an exception for the certificate. This means I cannot record a session.

Anyone know how I can handle this?

Comment: Hi, could you show what you get in browser ? and in jmeter if anything ? Thanks

Comment: I got the unknown certificate message but unlike with other sites, there was no option to add an an exception.

Comment: I have found a workaround using blazemeter to record my session. However this does not resolve the actual HSTS issue I've posted about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have option of using HAR to jmeter :

- https://blog.flood.io/convert-har-files-to-jmeter-test-plans/

But showing your error might help

Answer (score 1):

Websites using HSTS won't allow you to add exception for a server. What you can do is to tweek your browser to allow/bypass the HSTS policy. Here's what you can do in case of Firefox -

1. Type `about:support` in your browser to open up Troubleshooting Information page. (Alternatively, select 'Troubleshooting Information' from the Help Menu).
2. Navigate to the 'Profile Folder' row in the table shown on the page, and click the button 'Open Folder'
3. This would open up a new explorer window for the firefox profile directory. Keeping this explorer window open, close/quit Firefox.
4. Open the file `SiteSecurityServiceState.txt` and delete any rows containing your server name you need to access. Save this file. 
   After this, when you launch firefox, it would ignore HSTS restriction. 
   Source : [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1159143)

An alternate solution is to use the JMeter Chrome Plugin - [BlazeMeter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en)